# How select Span form first ul when it contain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filemaker

i have a script who choose `ADULTE - EROTIQUE` from 1st list

```
$('span:contains(" ADULTE - EROTIQUE")').trigger('click');
```

but then in the second list it's still choosing from the 1st list instead of choosing "​ADULTE- SOUFFLE​" in the second list

```
$('span:contains("​ADULTE- SOUFFLE")').trigger('click');
```

i think it find `ADULTE` and choose it because it s the first

How could i change the script to chose from, the 1st `<ul data-lvlcat="1">`
and then second script be executed in `<ul data-lvlcat="2">`

here is the code

```
<div class="prodUnitCat">
    <ul data-lvlcat="1">
        <li data-idcat="388780">
            <span>ABONNEMENT / SERVICES</span> (21)
        </li>
        <li data-idcat="100329409">
            <span>ADULTE - EROTIQUE</span> (7)
        </li>

    </ul>
​</div>
​<ul id=​"divChildrenCategoryFilter_0" class=​"fixFacetZindex clearBoth">​</ul>​
<ul data-lvlcat=​"2">​
    <li data-idcat=​"100039717">​
        <span>​ADULTE- SOUFFLE​</span>​
        " (22)"
    </li>​
    <li data-idcat=​"17709857" class=​"prodUnitSelectCat">​
        <span>​ARME D'ARTS MARTIAUX - DE COMBAT - COUTELLERIE​</span>​
        " (14)"
    </li>​
</ul>
```

Comment: Provide some working example like plunkr/jSfiddle. It will help everyone to understand it better.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tsb81vjk/ works fine for me.

Comment: in my software it s selecting always from the first list and if it s didn't find it s going to the next list.

Comment: Please try to compare your and my code. If you can reproduce problem in fiddle then i can take a look.

Comment: sorry i can't reproduce it more, if you have any ideas i will try them all :) 
could i add like path to the Ul 1 and to another script to Ul 2 ? 

or could i make match exactly the string ?